# dispatchOperation.Formatter NULL when call soap service

Tags: wcf

I have IDispatchMessageFormatter implementation

```
    class ServerMessageFormatter : IDispatchMessageFormatter
{
    private IDispatchMessageFormatter Formatter;

    public ServerMessageFormatter(IDispatchMessageFormatter formatter)
    {
        this.Formatter = formatter;
    }

    public void DeserializeRequest(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, object[] parameters)
    {
        Formatter.DeserializeRequest(message, parameters);
    }
}
```

and in  OperationBegavior

```
        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
    {
        ServerMessageFormatter Formatter = new ServerMessageFormatter(dispatchOperation.Formatter);
        dispatchOperation.Formatter = Formatter;
    }
```

and call soap service

```
  GetInfoRequest message = CheckedFields;
    string soap = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            <soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">
              <soap12:Header>
                <Action soap12:mustUnderstand=""1"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"">ServiceModel/IService/GetSoapData</Action>
              </soap12:Header>
            <soap12:Body>
        <GetInfoRequest  xmlns=""ServiceModel"">
            <Data xmlns:d4p1=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""/>
        </GetInfoRequest>
        </soap12:Body>
        </soap12:Envelope>";
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GetInfoRequest));
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://dev.add.renault.com/Service.svc/soap");
    MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.Serialize(stream1, message);
    stream1.Position = 0;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
    string t = sr.ReadToEnd();
    t = t.Remove(0, 22).Trim();
    t = string.Format(soap, t);
    ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
    request.Timeout = 99999999;
    request.ContentLength = t.Length;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
    request.Accept = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";

    using (Stream stm = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
        {
            stmw.Write(t);
        }
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var abc = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Problem is that when I call my REST service and set breakpoint in DeserializeRequest I see that Formatter has set value from Operation Behavior. But when call soap service my Formatter has null value and deserialization was aborted.  Why when calling soap I have that problem? Any idea?

Unfortunatelly  I can not fire breakpoint in Operaration Behavior and see what value have dispatchOperation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show how you configure your service to add your custom IDispatchMessageFormatter extension. So just taking a guess here, you may be adding it only to the webHttpBinding endpoint and not to the soap based binding endpoint. If you are using the WebHttpBehavior  methods (GetRequestDispatchFormatter & GetReplyDispatchFormatter) then this won't apply to your soap endpoints. This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx) has a good overview of how to use IDispatchMessageFormatter with webHttpBinding and basicHttpBinding.

EDIT:
The specific code in the article that shows how to add the a custom message formatter to the basicHttpBinding is below. Just prior to that section, he explains why this approach is necessary.

```
    //--- snipped ---//

    string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
    ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
    endpoint.Contract.Operations.Find("Add").Behaviors.Add(new MyOperationBehaviorAttribute());
    host.Open();

    //--- snipped ---//
```

Comment: Yes I use webHttpBinding for rest and customBinding for soap. For rest I add formatter in WebHttpBehavior. It's possible that I don't add it for soap binding. Which part of code id post u link is responsible for add formatter to soap binding? I have problem with find it :/

Comment: You were right. I must add to my customEndpoint webhttpBehavior

Comment: Im not using a self hosted option, but looks like I am having the same issue, how would I add the behaviours as you suggest here?