# WCF Service Error - DispatchOperation requires Formatter

Tags: wcf

I recently started getting an error when browsing one of my WCF services (from IIS) and I have no idea what the root cause is at the moment.  Any input would be appreciated as I can't seem to find much (if anything) on the web about it.

I should note that the service is configured no differently than other services I have that are running fine.

The error is:

The DispatchOperation '[service method]' requires Formatter, since DeserializeRequest and SerializeReply are not both false.

Comment: It sounds like you have something wrong in your config.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741658/dispatchoperation-formatter-null-when-call-soap-service

Comment: I don't think so - at least nothing that I can see.  The configuration for this service is exactly the same as 6 other services I have defined in the same web.config file (and they all work fine).

Comment: Is `The DispatchOperation '[service method]'` inheriting from another object?  Sometimes the serializers have problems with inheritance and it only shows up when you change .NET versions (go from 4 to 4.5 or 4.5 to 4.5.2).